# How to "click" a button using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

So, im trying to make a program that can click a button from multiple links, links that i will get from a list, but first i need to understand how can I do this with only one link. They all have the same HTML structure, but I dont know how to do this.

HTML:

```html
<div class="_55wr">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQG7lSxYN2mb:AQFMMcWJcZtZ" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="jazoest" value="22090" autocomplete="off">
        <table class="btnBar">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" value="Bloquear" class="_54k8 _52jg _56bs _26vk _56b_ _56bu" name="confirmed" data-sigil="touchable"><span class="_55sr">Bloquear</span></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" value="Cancelar" class="_54k8 _52jg _56bs _26vk _56b_ _56bt" name="canceled" data-sigil="touchable"><span class="_55sr">Cancelar</span></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

The idea is to click the first button ('<button type="submit" value="Bloquear"...').
Current code:

```
import requests

auth = ('email@email.com', 'pass')
payload = {}
url = 'https://www.example.com'

s = requests.Session()
res = s.get('https://www.example.com')
cookies = res.cookies

r = requests.post(url, cookies = cookies,  auth = auth, verify = False, payload = payload)
```

I searched for similar questions, but every question was using some "id" (`{'id':'value'}`), which I don't have here. So, what value should i use in payload?

Comment: If you open up dev tools (for example f11 if using chrome browser) the network tab will show you the actual post request made by your browser when you click a button.

Comment: It may also be worth at least looking into using selenium to drive an actual browser if it makes your life easier.

Comment: I would recommend to use Selenium so that you can mock the behaviour

Comment: @AdamHughes I had some trouble figuring out how to use what's on the network tab in the Python requests library. For example, I see "Headers", "Payload", and "Cookies". Under "Payload", I see `red=10&green=11&blue=12&control_led=Send+command+to+LED` (specific to my application). Should this be encoded as a string or a dictionary? Under "Headers" I see the URL, that it's a POST method, and request and response headers. I'm not sure what and how much needs to be encoded. Any comments here? Seems like it would be really useful as an answer with some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests library makes HTTP requests which means that it does not render the JS and it can not click buttons. Monitor your network behavior using google dev tools to know what data are sent to the server when you click a button, and then make a POST request sending the same data by the params keyword in the request. For example

```
data = {'button' : 'clicked1'}
r.requests.post('your_url.com', params = data)
```

For clicking buttons, I would personally use the selenium library which emulates the browser and provides its automation

Comment: So, i didn't want to use selenium since i didn't know anything about it. But i gave it a chance and after some few searches i got it now, much more easier. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @xmz_to can you post the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Selenium.

The code would be like so:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@value = \'Bloquear\']")
button.click()
```